# How to get average on Mongoid when using Money-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, currency, money-rails

I'm using Money-Rails as field like so:

```
class Product
  ...
  field :price_GBP, type: Money
  ...
end
```

And I'm trying to get the average for all `price_GBP` documents. If the `price_GBP` field were a float or integer I would something like this:

```
avg = Product.avg(:price_GBP)
```

And that would provide me the average price for all products. I've tried:

```
avg = Product.avg(":price_GBP.cents") #or
avg = Product.avg("price_GBP.fractional")
```

But neither works. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here's the `price_GBP` attribute:

```
price_GBP: {
    cents: 220,
    currency_iso: "GBP"
},
```

Comment: Have you looked at how `Money` is stored in the database? Does the documentation say anything? Have you looked at a raw `price_GBP` value without Mongoid in the way?

Comment: Money is a hash (in the Edit above), which is why I thought `Product.avg(":price_GBP.cents")` would do the trick. The Money documentation doesn't say anything and I'm trying to find in the Mongoid docs how to get average on a nested object without having to use the aggregation framework.

Comment: Try a simple `Model.avg(some_field)` in the console and then look at your Moped logs, you should see an aggregation behind the scenes. Have you tried `Product.avg('price_GBP.cents')` (i.e. no colon inside the string)? If that doesn't work then I guess you're stuck dealing with all the aggregation pipeline ugliness yourself.

Comment: `Product.avg("price_GBP.fractional")`, there's not `fractional` in your embedded document. Try the [arithmetic functions of the aggregation pipline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) to do simple calculations inside mongodb.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll do you want to add as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Nah, i'm happy if your code is workin :)